# How to change currency in PayPal for 3rd-party shopping cart checkout?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using this PayPal payment method in my project and I facing one issue in currency.

I have followed this link steps(https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside#methodone) and integrated PayPal, all things working fine but the currency showing wrong on the checkout page but when going to the next page it is showing properly.

I want to change the currency text from USD to EUR on the checkout page. how it is possible.

Can any help with it?

here is code

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="frmTransaction" id="frmTransaction">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="Email">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">   
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure to pass `currency_code="EUR"` to submit a form? add the code that you tried

Comment: Yes I have passed currency code EUR, Still I am getting USD in this page but when I do next page I am getting EUR.

Comment: @Siddharthi have added code in the question

Comment: You need to add `EUR` currency to your Paypal  account, check my answer

Comment: @Siddharth already followed that step but still in that page showing USD

Comment: may you please add updated form in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245171/discussion-between-siddharth-and-lakhan-p).

Comment: @Siddharth Thank you for the help such a great help.

Answer (score 1):

1, Add `EUR` currency to your Paypal account [using this link](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/money)

like this screenshot [image]

OR

Go to > Account Settings > BUSINESS PROFILE > Money, banks and cards > Currency management

2, Remove these two elements from your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
```

your final form code like below

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="frmTransaction" id="frmTransaction">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="web91.siddharth@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="">    
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">   
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">     
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay Now">
</form>
```